# Div alignment inside a <th>

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have a problem with a div alignment inside a .

I'am made a small fiddle to show the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/jpq7xzoz/

I use the jQuery tablesort-Plugin and display with a second div some buttons in the header. For e.g. a search icon to show/hide the filter.

```
<th class="header" style="text-align: center">
     <div class="header-inner">Patchlevel</div>
     <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
     </div>
</th>
```

But when the columns have a different size, then the table use a autosize for the cols and the div with the button wrap to a new line. But the head-description should at the same line as the button and the background-image.

When I take the button in the same div as the description then they are at the same line but i can't set the button at the right column.

I try to use different display-styles and the withe-space property but with no success.

What could I do?

Thx Felix

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jpq7xzoz/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hei!
Try to use negative margin.
For example:

```
.header-inner {margin-right:50px;}
.header-inner-filter {margin-left:-40px;}
```

Adjust 50px and -40px as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table-cell` instead of using `floats`:

```css
table {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
.header {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  padding: 4px 18px 4px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-inner-filter {
  display: table-cell;/*remove float and add table-cell*/
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header-inner {
  display: table-cell;/*remove float and add table-cell*/
}
.filterButton {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAAXNSR0ICQMB9xQAAAAlwSFlzAAAXEgAAFxIBZ5/SUgAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUATWljcm9zb2Z0IE9mZmljZX/tNXEAAADuSURBVDjLnZShDsIwEIYnJyeRSByTyEkkElm5x1jVJHJykkdAIieRk8hJJIIQuIbb8qfp9diWfO7v1/Z6t8RamyD0HYiauDInwvi5EChZERfiI9ARG1XGokdENPIkCk3mn6gh9m4hXxk3uhNpUMY1iu5M35oYIFdLskYLcdBg/STZDUJFRJbhDSRZD6E8IkuxrpLsDKEyIttBrpdkJYRckTMh2EGulWQZP/e0q2sLCOSe6CU177ig+KNhkUobp6MyBW9N6N/ZjVXrvfDAj7QNTEolytS/wq89ROEsmSacLYsI80WygNAsPpknnHryC/EXoeLKpmsfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-color: Transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <THEAD>
    <tr>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Patchlevel</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Patcheintrag</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Informationen</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Handulungsempfehlung</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
  </TBODY>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `.header-inner` and `.header-inner-filter` to `display:inline-block`

```css
table {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
.header {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  padding: 4px 18px 4px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-inner-filter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.header-inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
.filterButton {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAAXNSR0ICQMB9xQAAAAlwSFlzAAAXEgAAFxIBZ5/SUgAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUATWljcm9zb2Z0IE9mZmljZX/tNXEAAADuSURBVDjLnZShDsIwEIYnJyeRSByTyEkkElm5x1jVJHJykkdAIieRk8hJJIIQuIbb8qfp9diWfO7v1/Z6t8RamyD0HYiauDInwvi5EChZERfiI9ARG1XGokdENPIkCk3mn6gh9m4hXxk3uhNpUMY1iu5M35oYIFdLskYLcdBg/STZDUJFRJbhDSRZD6E8IkuxrpLsDKEyIttBrpdkJYRckTMh2EGulWQZP/e0q2sLCOSe6CU177ig+KNhkUobp6MyBW9N6N/ZjVXrvfDAj7QNTEolytS/wq89ROEsmSacLYsI80WygNAsPpknnHryC/EXoeLKpmsfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-color: Transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <THEAD>
    <tr>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Patchlevel</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Patcheintrag</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Informationen</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="header-inner">Handulungsempfehlung</div>
        <div class="header-inner-filter">
          <button class="filterButton"></button>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
  </TBODY>
</table>
```

Comment: add `vertical-align: top` along with `inline-block`

Comment: But then the button and the descripton are centered in the middle. And i would the description fixed to the left side and the button fixed to the right side.

Comment: @fjung You can add `padding-left: 50px;` to `.header-inner-filter`, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Change a bit of CSS for both divs.

```
.header-inner-filter {
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.header-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jpq7xzoz/4/)**